# Giving display none to fontawesome i tag does not work but .fas class does

Tags: css, class, tags, font-awesome

when I give display none to `<i class="fas fa-times"></i>` tag it does not work

```
header nav i {
    display: none; /*if I add !important it works too*/
}
```

however, it works well for .fas class.

```
header nav .fas {
display: none;
```

}

Why do they act differently?

Answer (score 1):

CSS has a concept of specificity. Browsers use specificity to decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied.

Here is MDN tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
And here you can paste a CSS selector to find out it's specificity: https://polypane.app/css-specificity-calculator/